# Change view and controller without updating url or history

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a quiz game using Angularjs, there are three layouts. One for intro, question and bonus questions. I am trying to create it without changing the url or history since users are not allowed to go back and change their answer. Is this possible or should I be trying to do this in the same route, controller and view, show hiding layouts.

or is there a better way to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can create your own simple non-url "router" using `ngInclude`.

Comment: I know this is not the point, but you can't really ensure that your users won't "cheat" until you use a server. For example, send answers to a server after every question so you are sure that a same visitor can't answer twice.

Comment: Yes, every answer is going to be saved on the server. Thanke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ngInclude` (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) to change template according to quiz progress, please see sample demo here 
http://plnkr.co/edit/jq63ULx2ZrRC9rbJJzOY?p=preview

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">   
    <a href="" ng-click="next()">Next Question</a>
    <hr/>
    <div ng-include="template"></div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'World';
    $scope.q = 1;
    $scope.template = "view1.html";
    $scope.next = function() {
        if ($scope.q < 4) {
            $scope.q++;
            $scope.template = "view" + $scope.q + ".html";
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This looks promising, Thanks

Comment: Can I manage from the MainCtrl the variables (inputs) I might request from each different view? or Do I have to create a different controller for each one?

Answer (score 3):

As I said in comments it should be pretty easy to create own very simple routes similar to native `$route` but which would work with `ngInclude` directive. Out of curiosity I came up with this implementation:

```
angular.module('simpleRoute', []).provider('simpleRoute', function() {

    var routes = {},
        stack = [],
        currentRoute;

    this.when = function(path, config) {
        config.path = path;
        routes[path] = config;
        return this;
    };

    this.setCurrent = function(path) {
        currentRoute = routes[path];
    };

    function triggerChange(newRoute) {
        stack.forEach(function(callback) {
            callback(newRoute, currentRoute);
        });
        currentRoute = newRoute;
    }

    this.$get = function() {
        return {
            onRouteChange: function(callback) {
                stack.push(callback);
            },
            path: function(path) {
                if (!path) {
                    return currentPath;
                }
                triggerChange(routes[path], currentRoute);
            },
            getCurrent: function() {
                return currentRoute;
            }
        };
    }
})

.directive('simpleView', function($controller, simpleRoute) {
    return {
        template: '<div ng-include="templatePath"></div>',
        link: function($scope) {

            simpleRoute.onRouteChange(function(newRoute, oldRoute) {
                $scope.templatePath = newRoute.templateUrl;
                $controller(newRoute.controller, { $scope: $scope });
            });

            var currentRoute = simpleRoute.getCurrent();
            if (currentRoute) {
                simpleRoute.path(currentRoute.path);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Then this guy would be used like this:

```
app.config(function(simpleRouteProvider) {
    simpleRouteProvider
    .when('/', {
        controller: 'step0Controller',
        templateUrl: 'step0.html'
    })
    .when('step1', {
        controller: 'step1Controller',
        templateUrl: 'step1.html'
    })
    .setCurrent('/');
});
```

And HTML should be configured:

```
<div simple-view></div>
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/u03zden3OtK1LFK25bSP?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you for your routing system, but now i have a problem, in the div simple-view, i think the JS is not executed, Here http://dev.enzo-bianchi.fr/  , in "My project"
The first tab are in the index.html, and the second tab are in a partial in the div simple-view